# Page posting after session expired in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, session

I am working on a ASP.net application. I have some code in the page init event and using some session variables.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {

               if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ApplicationUser"] == null)
                    // If Session Expires then reload the user roles.
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("ApplicationUser");
                    var userService = new UserService();
                    var userRoles = userService.GetUserRoles(userName);
                    if (userRoles.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/UnAuthorized.aspx", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isAuthunticated = true;
                        roles = userRoles;
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["ApplicationUser"] = userRoles;
                    }
                }
}
```

Note: I am not using any session variables apart from this two places.
The default session  timeout value is 20 mins.
I opened a page and left the system idle for 30 mins. After 30 mins, I filled some fields in the page and hits save button(now page is posting and the session is expired)

In this scenario, system will accept the post request if the session is expired?

Comment: there is no way to do it but you can take help of javascript which alert when session get expired

Comment: Hi Pranay, Thanks for the quick reply. So the server will not accept the post request and the page Init event will not be called once the session is expired.